# Stock price data refresh

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2, stockquotes

I am very new and I am getting totally stuck with recent task. I want to autorefresh stock price automatically as it is changing. I am scrapping nasdaq.com
website for actual intraday price.
I have a recent code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib
tiker = input("zadaj ticker: ")
url = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/"+tiker+"/real-time")
stranka = url.read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(stranka, 'lxml')
print (tiker.upper())
for each in soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'qwidget_lastsale'}):
    print(each.string)
```

I was only able to make an infinite loop while True but i get prints in lines despite i want to change only one line as actual price is changing.
very thank you for your notes.

Comment: You could construct a gui to achieve what you want - https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by printing "\b" to remove the previously printed string and then printing on the same line:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib
import time
import sys

tiker = input("zadaj ticker: ")
print (tiker.upper())
written_string = ''
while True:
    url = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/"+tiker+"/real-time")
    stranka = url.read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(stranka, 'lxml')
    for each in soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'qwidget_lastsale'}):
        for i in range(len(written_string)):
            sys.stderr.write("\b")
        sys.stderr.write(each.string)
        written_string = each.string
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: thank you sir.
can you give me a hint how to overwrite the previous print as the price is changing... Your code just prints prices in line but want to just one print which is changing as a price change